# Can we create and use our own interface instead of defined by the java?

Tags: java, try-with-resources

<s>Q1 : *(removed)*</s>

Q2 : `try-with-resource` to create own resource implement `AutoCloseable` interface and override `close()` method.

From javadoc

> Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

So, here I created a simple program `MyAuto.java`

```
class Demo implements AutoCloseable {
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("show");
    }
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("close from demo");
    }
}

class MyAuto {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(Demo d = new Demo()) {
            int x = 10/0;
            d.show();
        }catch(ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This program runs fine. :) and giving output

`close from demo` : as expected, no matters exception occurs, d will be closed.

But my question is I didn't write any code that close this resource, I simply put a print statement. What here actually closing a resource mean ? Assigning `null` to reference variable of resource or anything else ?
Or `JVM` runs any other method after running `close()` behind the scene.

And finally the most important question..

Q3 : In the above scenario if I add my own interface `AutoCloseable`

```
interface AutoCloseable {
    void close() throws Exception;
}
```

It gives compile time error on compiling `MyAuto.java`

`error: incompatible types: try-with-resources not applicable to variable type
              try(Demo d = new Demo()) {
                     ^
  (Demo cannot be converted to AutoCloseable)`.

So, please give me answer why it's happening. Why can't we create and use our own Interfaces instead of provided by java. What is difference between my interface and the one predefined, although both are same.

Comment: Please visit [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735)

Comment: And have you looked up how try-with-resources work? I suspect the internet is full of guides on them.

Comment: sorry for the first question but 2nd and third are related @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @SandeepRawat: Fair enough, I've taken the liberty of removing the first question (since doing so didn't seem to invalidate either posted answer). (If you disagree with removing it, you can use the "rollback" feature -- click the "Edited XYZ ago" link and you'll see it.)

Comment: @Carcigenicate everyone talks about how , that's I know but I want to know about why ? that's why I posted here

Answer (score 0):

> What is difference between my interface and the one predefined, although both are same.

They're ***not*** the same.  Not by a long shot.

The `AutoCloseable` required for `try-with-resources` is `java.lang.AutoCloseable`.  *Your* custom `AutoCloseable` doesn't come from that package, so Java isn't going to respect it.

Above all, introducing that would not be the best approach, since it'll only lead to confusing semantics and a bad experience later down the road, even if you elected to have your interface extend `java.lang.AutoCloseable` for whatever reason.

In the same vein...

> ...I didn't write any code that close this resource, I simply put a print statement. What here actually closing a resource mean ? Assigning null to reference variable of resource or anything else ? Or JVM runs any other method after running close() behind the scene.

The interface can't enforce anything like that.  All it can do is provide a mechanism that, if well-implemented, will behave as you expect.